# Codeigniter: having issue with fetching data as sum of columns

Tags: codeigniter, select, count, fetch

i am new to Codeigniter, i have two tables named as Users and Amount, there are multiple amounts in Amount Table across one user have same user_id which is foreign key. i want to get data and sum up the amounts value if user_id is same.

My Modal is:

```
public function client_list(){
$this->db->select_sum('*', sum('amount'));
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('amount', 'amount.user_id = users.ID');
$query=$this->db->get();
$result=$query->result();
return $result;
}
```

Controller is:

```
public function index(){
$data['records'] = $this->Admin_model->client_list();
    $this->load->view('admin/Client_list', $data);
}
```

View part is:

```
<?php
     foreach($records as $record):
?>

<tr class="odd gradeX">
 <td>
  <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1" />
  <span></span>
  </label>
 </td>
 <td> <?php echo $record->firstname;  ?> </td>
 <td> <?php  echo $record->lastname; ?> </td>
 <td> <?php  echo $record->phone;?> </td>
 <td> <?php  echo $record->email;?> </td>
 <td> <?php  echo $record->amount;?> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $record->dateofbirth;?> </td>
</tr>
<?php   endforeach;  ?>
```

Kind Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: ...and the issue is?

Comment: `select_sum('*')` throws error dude, you need to specify the fields